# getting error while using PrimeFaces 3 on inputTextArea...javax.servlet.ServletException: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender()

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to use inputTextArea but i am getting error

**javax.servlet.ServletException: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;)Ljava/lang/String;**. Here is my code

```
<ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
         <ui:define name="title">Add News</ui:define>
         <ui:define name="content">
             <h:form id="news_advertisement_form" prependId="false" >
                 <div id="outerboxmid">
                     <div id="outboxmidborder">
                         <div id="outboxmidpg">
                             <div id="formaddupdategrey"> 
                                 <div class="MainHeader">
                                     <h:outputLabel value="Add News"/>
                                 </div>
                                 <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                                     <h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="Firstname: *" />
                                     <p:inputText id="firstname" value="Basit" label="Firstname" />
                                 </p:panelGrid>                             
                             </div> 
                         </div> 
                     </div> 
                 </div>  
             </h:form>
         </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</h:body>
```

why i am getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: What version of primefaces are you using?

Comment: its a stable one? or nightly build or something? , b.t.w try removing the p:panelGrid wrap... its a new component... maybe its some bug, worth trying

Comment: It's stable [link]http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html . No, error is caused by the line `<p:inputText id="firstname" value="Basit" label="Firstname" />`. If i remove this line, then the code works.

Comment: just for you to know it works perfectly in 3.0 final , any way replace the value="Basit" with value="#{myBean.myPropertie}"

Comment: Please do not post only the first line of the stacktrace. The bottommost root cause is the most interesting part. Always post the entire stacktrace if you want a reliable answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the value of your `p:inputText`.

```
value="Basit"
```

The error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;)Ljava/lang/String;

The Primefaces ComponentUtils class is trying to get the component value during the Render phase and it is probably expecting an EL expression that references a property or object from a managed bean.

Comment: No, i tried this, with the h:inputText it works fine. Here `<p:inputText value="#{news.headline}" />-><ui:remove><h:inputText value="#{news.headline}"style="width: 250px;"><f:validateLength maximum="250" /></h:inputText></ui:remove>`. See, if i use h:inputText then the EL execute and everything works fine, But if i use p:inputText then i get error. Why? I am also using primefaces calender. No error. Although calender is not showing because of jQuery conflicts but at least page shown,  but in case of p:inputText i get error :(

Comment: @Basit jQuery conflicts?  That might be the problem right there.  You should only use the version of jQuery that comes bundled with PrimeFaces.

Comment: @BalucC @Daniel No i checked it, i removed the ui:composition line, now there is no .js file other than Prime faces but the problem is still there. Any way this is the root cause that i didn't post and BalucC point it out `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;)Ljava/lang/String;`

Comment: but after removing the ui:composition the calender is now showing. So this is obvious that calender is not showing because of jQuery conflict. Also i now used p:button instead of p:inputText and buttton is working. Something happening wrong in case of inputText. I tried it out in the new project and there inputText is working. So the library is OK